# selectInput based on columns of uploading csv file

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app where I can upload a csv file and based on the column names, from `selectInput` - app shows basic statistic (graphs, descriptive statistic-average, sd, var .... and some statistical tests). 
**There is no problem with datasets, which are already in the app. Also no problem with statistics.**
Problem is how to make working `selectInput` with the names of columns from new upload csv file.

Here is my light version of code:

UI:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("xxx"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("csvFile", "Drag cars.csv over here!"),
            selectInput("var", "choose variable:", choices= names(data()))
        ),

        mainPanel(
            textOutput("average"),
            plotOutput("plot")
        )
    )
))
```

SERVER:

```r
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive({
        file1 <- input$csvFile
        if (is.null(file1)) { 
            return() 
        } 
        data = read.csv(file=file1$datapath)
        data
    })
    output$average <- renderText({
        paste("average is: ", mean(data()[,input$var]))
    })
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        boxplot(data()[,input$var])
    })
})
```

Comment: Have a look at `updateSelectInput()`. Also, you may benefit from avoiding to name anything `"data"`. Even though it can work, it can be confusing because of the built-in function named `data()`

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use uiOutput() and renderUI() functions.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("xxx"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("csvFile", "Drag cars.csv over here!"),
      uiOutput("var_ui")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("average"),
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$csvFile
    if (is.null(file1)) { 
      return() 
    } 
    data = read.csv(file=file1$datapath)
    data
  })
  output$average <- renderText({
    paste("average is: ", mean(data()[,input$var]))
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    boxplot(data()[,input$var])
  })

  output$var_ui <- renderUI({
    selectInput("var", "choose variable:", choices= names(data()))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `observe` in server. `observe` does not return anything. Unlike `reactive`, it responds immediately (and not lazily). It's best used for ip/op operations.

```
observe({
  updateSelectInput(
    session,
    "var",
    choices = names(data())
  )
)}
```